# Using string pointers in a variable argument Function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, variadic-functions

**Question**
So as the title implies I am asking if there is a way to use stdarg.h for a text print in a variable argument function. I got the idea of making sort of a callendar that you could search through but I have the problem of finding/testing for a string that was inputed. I will be thankful for any suggestions.

**Code:**

```
void CinemaPrint(int count,...)
{
    va_list k;
    va_start(k,count);
    int i=0;
    for(i=1;i<count+1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n\n",i, va_arg(k,int));
    }
    va_end (k);
    char textz[]="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    scanf("%s",&textz);
    char* pointer=(char*)(&count+1);
    for(i=1;i<count+1;i++)
    {
        if(textz==*pointer)
        {
            printf("Cinema %s is %d.",*pointer, i);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello kino!\n");
    char text1[]="Cinema City";
    char text2[]="Hutnik";
    char text3[]="Svetozor";
    char text4[]="Lucerna";
    char text5[]="Flora3D";

    CinemaPrint(5,text1,text2,text3,text4,text5);


    return 0;
}
```

**What it does**

```
Hello kino!
Cinema City

Hutnik

Svetozor

Lucerna

Flora3D

Hutnik //this was inputed from me. After this it ends
```

**What I want it to do**

```
Hello kino!
Cinema City

Hutnik

Svetozor

Lucerna

Flora3D

Hutnik

Cinema Hutnik is 2.
```

Comment: Use the `strcmp` function.  You cannot compare two strings using `==`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues here.

First, you can't manually iterate through the variable argument list with `char* pointer=(char*)(&count+1);`  You need to call `va_start` and `va_end` again using a different `va_list` instance.  You should also be retrieving the argument as `char *` instead of `int` so that type argument types match.

Second, you can't compare strings with `==`.  That will just compare the addresses of each one.  You need `strcmp` to do that.

```
char textz[]="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
scanf("%s",textz);

va_list k2;
va_start(k2, count);
for(i=1;i<count+1;i++)
{
    char *pointer = va_arg(k2, char *);
    if(!strcmp(textz,pointer))
    {
        printf("Cinema %s is %d.",pointer, i);
    }
}
va_end(k2);
```